# Все шляпы хороши́?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, перевод

Я люблю шляпы — и в обычной жизни, и в работе на форуме.
К великому сожалению, некоторые наши шляпы почиканы "орфографической молью".
[**Вот**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/177519/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9#winter-bash) (парадная, противоковидная, солнечная, шевелюро-гнездовая):

> Задайте вопрос, ответьте или проголосуйте **в течении 21-го декабря** (эта шляпа имеет два вида, но получить можно лишь одну за раз).

Думаю, что надо бы исправить: *в течение 21 декабря*.

Просто для сведения:
[В течение](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)
[Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)

Просто P. S. В небольшой Эстонии народ хитрый: умудряется отметить и католическое (или лютеранское) рождество, и православное — с разницей в 13 дней.
Все мы (и здесь, на форуме) — разные, но пожелаю всем-всем только одного — ***здорового** Нового года!*

Comment: Просто все эти переводы делались скрытно, дабы не раскрывать шляпы раньше времени, без консультаций со справочником или экспертами. Как следствие - переводы хромают. Есть ещё и несоответствия с принятыми на сайте нормами, например, [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11222/176217). Учитывая сезонность мероприятия, ошибки, скорее всего, не будут исправлены вовсе.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! Жаль, правда, что скрытность влияет на грамотность. Возможно, эти поправки помогут в будущем — негоже, когда в модераторских текстах имеются ошибки. С Новым годом! Успехов!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отправил просьбу исправить перевод. Спасибо вам и с наступающими праздниками!

Comment: И Вам, Aer, — хорошего настроения, добра и здравия.

Answer (score 1):

Большое спасибо за указание на дефект и ссылки на правила. Постараюсь выучить правила в течение 2021 года, чтобы в следующий раз не допустить ошибок =)

Comment: И Вам поклон, _Nicolas Chabanovsky♦_, — за внимание к моему вопросу и оптимистический настрой.